facing issue when customize month order in locale Ja with bsdatepicker
const customMonthOrder: number[] = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1]; // March to February

// Get the default full month names
const defaultMonthNames: string[] = jaLocale.months as string[];

// Create an array of full month names in the custom order
const customMonthNames: string[] = customMonthOrder.map(index => defaultMonthNames[index]);

// Create an array of short month names in the custom order
const customMonthShortNames: string[] = customMonthNames.map(month => month.slice(0, 3)); // Take the first 3 characters as short names

// Create the custom locale object
const customLocale = {
  ...jaLocale,
  months: customMonthNames,
  monthsShort: customMonthShortNames,
};

// Define the custom locale
defineLocale('ja-custom', customLocale);

enter image description here
above image what happend
in this scenario label are change but value sequnce still as it's if i will select month 2 and input field select 12 month so what is the solution.
expected behaviour is japan calender budget year start from march and end feb so that thing i want change custom order month
